# Where does the daily excess reputation points go?

Tags: discussion

I have just today reached a milestone and received over 200 reputation in a single day but I'm still receiving up votes today (in excess of the 200 max). I actually got capped at 215 but the up-vote notices are still coming in. What happens to that rep? Will those rep points be awarded tomorrow?

Comment: It's just gone.

Comment: I collect it, for my retirement.

Comment: Spirited away in the night, like teeth.

Comment: OK, it's a new day so you can upvote this question now.

Comment: @Morgan - Meta votes don't affect your rep on main site.

Comment: @DVK So what is 'Meta'. I'm not a computer person so some of this is... unusual and strange to me.

Comment: @Morgan - Meta means "self-referential". Like making a documentary about the process of making a documentary.

Comment: @Richard-That makes sense. That level of interaction and information exchange itself is interesting and informative. Dare I say 'edifying'?

Comment: @Morgan - Meta is only cool if it's not pretentious. If meta is **about meta** then it's not meta.

Comment: @Richard-Observer effect? Makes sense. I still want my stolen rep though.

Comment: @DVK has written an evil script, directing all excess rep to his account. How else did you think he got to have 100k+ rep?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Reputation above the cap just disappears into the void. But you get a [shiny new badge](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges/25/mortarboard?userid=13090) for it.

The reason you got 215 is because the 15 points from an accept don't count towards the maximum (same with bounties).

Comment: What kind of rip-off is that? I want to talk to the management. I have a reputation to protect here!!!  Note: The 200 daily cap has only been awarded 181 times. The 'Epic' badge (200x50) has only awarded 5 times and 'Legendary' (200x150) status has been reached but once. With such a cap and the low numbers reaching it, how can these guys get 50k, 75k, 100k reputation in just a couple years?

Comment: Stop up-voting my question!!!!......... Wait till tomorrow.

Comment: So far today, I've been ripped-off by 115 rep points and counting. This is just a plot to keep the little people down!

Comment: Happens to everyone. Or rather, 181 people so far on this site.

Comment: @morgan, even though I've achieved the epic badge, I share your pain. I also managed to garner over 20K rep in under a hundred days so there's no reason to assume the legendary badge is out of reach.

Comment: @Morgan - just do the math. If you got 200 rep, say, 60 times - that's 12K rep alone. But that only counts for 60 days out of 2+ years. If you say the OTHER 600+ days, they averaged 100 rep, that's 60K rep, for a total of 72K. So that's how the highest rep users could hit a high rep  total quickly without getting the Legendary badge.

Comment: I just got nicked for another 25 rep points. Aargh! That makes for a current total of 140 'stolen' points today. I'm just a poor poster and every little bit I can scrape together goes to paying the bills. Tomorrow I'll probably only 'earn' about 25 rep points. Why can't 'the powers that be' carry forward that earned rep to the next day's tally (up to the 200 rep cap)? That would only put me at a generous forecast of 165 rep for the day. They carry forward excess payments on my phone, PUD, car pmt., etc.. Why not here?  How does that break the bank or game the system?

Comment: @Morgan - welcome to the world of my cell phone bills :(

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that your additional reputation is gone and ain't coming back.

The cap allegedly exists to prevent "gaming" of the system. You can read the justification [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22447/what-is-the-reasoning-behind-the-reputation-cap) and if you want to, you can upset yourself by visiting Data Explorer and checking the "**How high would my reputation be if there wasn't a cap?**" page;

https://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/166741/how-high-would-my-reputation-approximately-be-when-there-was-no-cap-or-cw

Comment: Won't be THAT upset. I lost quite a bit of rep to the cap; and even for me it was merely 30% loss, or even less.

Comment: @dvk - It annoys me, especially if you get lots of upvotes for a well-crafted answer only to realise they're all going into the toilet.

Comment: @Rihard - yes. That's why they created it. To annoy us to go and get off the site (i'm not being facetious... that was stated on SOMeta by Atwood)

Comment: @dvk - I spotted it. Apparently we're supposed to get out into the real world. I've tried that and I didn't like it...